# monerod does not start to sync via my dsl connection, but it continues to sync when I start via other connection

Tags: monerod, synchronization

I have two internet connections, dsl and mobile. monerod never starts to sync via dsl connection, but it starts to sync via my phone's mobile internet successfully. After it starts to sync, I stop running monerod and connect to dsl again. When I run monerod again, it continues to sync well. So where the problem can be ? My dns addresses are 4.2.2.1 and 4.2.2.2 on the failing network. There is no working firewall on DSL router.

I am using monero 0.10.3.1 (Command-Line Tools Only). My operating system is debian 8.8 64 bit(fresh installation). I also tried to start synching via dsl connection with fresh Fedora Workstation and Windows 7(32 bit) installations, it did not.

Error part of logs:

```
2017-06-13 18:45:07.570 [P2P6] ERROR net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745 [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-13 18:45:07.570 [P2P4] ERROR net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794 [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
```

You can check the complete logs of monerod (I set log level to 2):

```
2017-06-13 18:40:38.003     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-06-13 18:40:38.029     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:282 Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.3.1-release)
2017-06-13 18:40:38.029     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:55    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2017-06-13 18:40:38.029     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:60    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2017-06-13 18:40:38.030     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63 Initializing p2p server...
2017-06-13 18:40:40.214     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:68 P2p server initialized OK
2017-06-13 18:40:40.215     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:58 Initializing core rpc server...
2017-06-13 18:40:40.215     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  contrib/epee/include/net/http_server_impl_base.h:70 Binding on 127.0.0.1:18081
2017-06-13 18:40:40.215     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:63 Core rpc server initialized OK on port: 18081
2017-06-13 18:40:40.215     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:73    Initializing core...
2017-06-13 18:40:40.251     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:326 Loading blockchain from folder /home/c/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2017-06-13 18:40:41.876     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:78    Core initialized OK
2017-06-13 18:40:41.877     7eff9b5d2740    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:68 Starting core rpc server...
2017-06-13 18:40:41.878 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:73 Core rpc server started ok
2017-06-13 18:40:41.878 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:78 Starting p2p net loop...
2017-06-13 18:40:42.879 [P2P1]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1098    
**********************************************************************
The daemon will start synchronizing with the network. It may take up to several hours.

You can set the level of process detailization* through "set_log " command*,
where  is between 0 (no details) and 4 (very verbose), or custom category based levels (eg, *:WARNING)

Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
**********************************************************************

set_log 2
2017-06-13 18:40:52.791     7eff98efd700    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:153   New log categories: *:DEBUG
2017-06-13 18:40:52.791     7eff98efd700    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:94   Log level is now 2
Log level is now 2
2017-06-13 18:40:52.880 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 195.154.123.123:28080
2017-06-13 18:40:52.880 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 198.74.231.92:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:40:52.880 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#3 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:4
2017-06-13 18:40:52.880 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:40:52.880 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 3
2017-06-13 18:40:57.881 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 198.74.231.92:18080
2017-06-13 18:40:57.881 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 212.83.172.165:28080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:40:57.882 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#4 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:5
2017-06-13 18:40:57.882 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:40:57.882 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 4
2017-06-13 18:40:57.955 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1657   [212.83.172.165:28080 745b365d-e118-6a19-7c52-e08eb87cc5b0 OUT] NEW CONNECTION
2017-06-13 18:40:57.955 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:270    connection type P2P 192.168.1.10:35352 <--> 212.83.172.165:28080
2017-06-13 18:40:57.955 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:539   do_send() NOW SENSD: packet=33 B
2017-06-13 18:40:57.955 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:267    handler_write (direct) - before ASIO write, for packet=33 B (after sleep)
2017-06-13 18:40:57.955 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:524   do_send() NOW just queues: packet=181 B, is added to queue-size=2
2017-06-13 18:40:57.955 [P2P8]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:634   handle_write() NOW SENDS: packet=181 B, from  queue size=1
2017-06-13 18:40:57.955 [P2P8]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:273    handler_write (after write, from queue=1) - before ASIO write, for packet=181 B (after sleep)
2017-06-13 18:41:02.955 [P2P3]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/levin_protocol_handler_async.h:157 [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] Timeout on invoke operation happened, command: 1001
2017-06-13 18:41:02.956 [P2P3]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/storages/levin_abstract_invoke2.h:125  Failed to invoke command 1001 return code -4
2017-06-13 18:41:02.956 [P2P3]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-13 18:41:02.957 [P2P0]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-13 18:41:03.003 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:946    [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] Failed to HANDSHAKE with peer 212.83.172.165:28080
2017-06-13 18:41:03.003 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 212.83.175.67:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:03.003 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#5 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:6
2017-06-13 18:41:03.003 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:03.003 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 5
2017-06-13 18:41:08.003 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 212.83.175.67:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:08.004 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 5.9.100.248:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:08.004 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#6 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:7
2017-06-13 18:41:08.005 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:08.005 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 6
2017-06-13 18:41:13.005 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 5.9.100.248:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:13.005 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 107.152.130.98:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:13.006 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#7 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:41:13.006 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:13.006 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:41:16.879 [P2P7]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#1 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:41:18.007 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 107.152.130.98:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:18.007 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 161.67.132.39:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:18.007 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#8 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:41:18.007 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:18.007 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:41:21.880 [P2P5]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#2 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:41:23.008 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 161.67.132.39:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:23.008 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 163.172.182.165:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:23.009 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#9 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:41:23.009 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:23.009 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:41:26.880 [P2P6]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#3 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:41:28.009 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 163.172.182.165:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.010 [P2P0]  WARN    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1118   Failed to connect to any of seed peers, trying fallback seeds
2017-06-13 18:41:28.010 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1121   Fallback seed node: 107.152.130.98:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.010 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:390    Added seed node: 107.152.130.98:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.010 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1121   Fallback seed node: 161.67.132.39:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.010 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:390    Added seed node: 161.67.132.39:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.010 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1121   Fallback seed node: 163.172.182.165:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:390    Added seed node: 163.172.182.165:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1121   Fallback seed node: 195.154.123.123:28080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:390    Added seed node: 195.154.123.123:28080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1121   Fallback seed node: 198.74.231.92:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:390    Added seed node: 198.74.231.92:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1121   Fallback seed node: 212.83.172.165:28080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:390    Added seed node: 212.83.172.165:28080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1121   Fallback seed node: 212.83.175.67:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:390    Added seed node: 212.83.175.67:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1121   Fallback seed node: 5.9.100.248:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:390    Added seed node: 5.9.100.248:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 195.154.123.123:28080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#10 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:28.011 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:41:31.880 [P2P8]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1663   [212.83.172.165:28080 745b365d-e118-6a19-7c52-e08eb87cc5b0 OUT] CLOSE CONNECTION
2017-06-13 18:41:31.881 [P2P8]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#4 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:41:33.012 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 195.154.123.123:28080
2017-06-13 18:41:33.012 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 198.74.231.92:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:33.013 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#11 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:41:33.013 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:33.013 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:41:36.881 [P2P2]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#5 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:41:38.014 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 198.74.231.92:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:38.014 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 212.83.172.165:28080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:38.014 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#12 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:41:38.015 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:38.015 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:41:38.090 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1657   [212.83.172.165:28080 a6b9e874-594c-5976-81ef-9b7e913f06eb OUT] NEW CONNECTION
2017-06-13 18:41:38.090 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:270    connection type P2P 192.168.1.10:35360 <--> 212.83.172.165:28080
2017-06-13 18:41:38.090 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:539   do_send() NOW SENSD: packet=33 B
2017-06-13 18:41:38.091 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:267    handler_write (direct) - before ASIO write, for packet=33 B (after sleep)
2017-06-13 18:41:38.091 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:524   do_send() NOW just queues: packet=181 B, is added to queue-size=2
2017-06-13 18:41:38.091 [P2P7]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:634   handle_write() NOW SENDS: packet=181 B, from  queue size=1
2017-06-13 18:41:38.091 [P2P7]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:273    handler_write (after write, from queue=1) - before ASIO write, for packet=181 B (after sleep)
2017-06-13 18:41:41.881 [P2P9]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#6 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:41:43.091 [P2P5]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/levin_protocol_handler_async.h:157 [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] Timeout on invoke operation happened, command: 1001
2017-06-13 18:41:43.091 [P2P5]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/storages/levin_abstract_invoke2.h:125  Failed to invoke command 1001 return code -4
2017-06-13 18:41:43.092 [P2P5]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-13 18:41:43.092 [P2P0]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-13 18:41:43.092 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:946    [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] Failed to HANDSHAKE with peer 212.83.172.165:28080
2017-06-13 18:41:43.093 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 212.83.175.67:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:43.093 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#13 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:41:43.093 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:43.093 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:41:46.882 [P2P4]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#7 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:41:48.093 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 212.83.175.67:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:48.093 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 5.9.100.248:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:48.094 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#14 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:41:48.094 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:48.094 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:41:51.882 [P2P3]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#8 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:41:53.094 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 5.9.100.248:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:53.095 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 107.152.130.98:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:53.095 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#15 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:41:53.095 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:53.095 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:41:56.882 [P2P4]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#9 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:41:58.095 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 107.152.130.98:18080
2017-06-13 18:41:58.095 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 161.67.132.39:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:41:58.095 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#16 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:41:58.095 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:41:58.095 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:42:01.883 [P2P9]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#10 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:42:03.096 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 161.67.132.39:18080
2017-06-13 18:42:03.096 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 163.172.182.165:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:42:03.096 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#17 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:42:03.096 [P2P0]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:42:03.096 [P2P0]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:42:06.883 [P2P3]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#11 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:42:08.097 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 163.172.182.165:18080
2017-06-13 18:42:08.097 [P2P0]  WARN    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1129   Failed to connect to any of seed peers, continuing without seeds
2017-06-13 18:42:09.097 [P2P9]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1215   STARTED PEERLIST IDLE HANDSHAKE
2017-06-13 18:42:09.097 [P2P9]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1227   FINISHED PEERLIST IDLE HANDSHAKE
2017-06-13 18:42:10.097 [P2P2]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 195.154.123.123:28080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:42:10.097 [P2P2]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#18 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:42:10.097 [P2P2]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:42:10.097 [P2P2]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:42:11.883 [P2P6]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1663   [212.83.172.165:28080 a6b9e874-594c-5976-81ef-9b7e913f06eb OUT] CLOSE CONNECTION
2017-06-13 18:42:11.883 [P2P6]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#12 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:42:15.098 [P2P2]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 195.154.123.123:28080
2017-06-13 18:42:15.098 [P2P2]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 198.74.231.92:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:42:15.098 [P2P2]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#19 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:42:15.098 [P2P2]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:42:15.098 [P2P2]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:42:16.884 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#13 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:42:20.099 [P2P2]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:932    [0.0.0.0:0 OUT] Connect failed to 198.74.231.92:18080
2017-06-13 18:42:20.099 [P2P2]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 212.83.172.165:28080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:42:20.099 [P2P2]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#20 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
2017-06-13 18:42:20.099 [P2P2]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:85    test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=2
2017-06-13 18:42:20.099 [P2P2]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:961   connections_ size now 7
2017-06-13 18:42:20.170 [P2P2]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:1657   [212.83.172.165:28080 5a831adc-8003-d983-245f-e0a725016b18 OUT] NEW CONNECTION
2017-06-13 18:42:20.170 [P2P2]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:270    connection type P2P 192.168.1.10:35383 <--> 212.83.172.165:28080
2017-06-13 18:42:20.170 [P2P2]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:539   do_send() NOW SENSD: packet=33 B
2017-06-13 18:42:20.171 [P2P2]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:267    handler_write (direct) - before ASIO write, for packet=33 B (after sleep)
2017-06-13 18:42:20.171 [P2P2]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:524   do_send() NOW just queues: packet=181 B, is added to queue-size=2
2017-06-13 18:42:20.171 [P2P8]  DEBUG   net contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:634   handle_write() NOW SENDS: packet=181 B, from  queue size=1
2017-06-13 18:42:20.171 [P2P8]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:273    handler_write (after write, from queue=1) - before ASIO write, for packet=181 B (after sleep)
2017-06-13 18:42:21.884 [P2P0]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:172    Destructing connection p2p#14 to 0.0.0.0
2017-06-13 18:42:25.171 [P2P1]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/net/levin_protocol_handler_async.h:157 [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] Timeout on invoke operation happened, command: 1001
2017-06-13 18:42:25.171 [P2P1]  INFO    net contrib/epee/include/storages/levin_abstract_invoke2.h:125  Failed to invoke command 1001 return code -4
2017-06-13 18:42:25.171 [P2P1]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-13 18:42:25.172 [P2P2]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-13 18:42:25.172 [P2P2]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:946    [212.83.172.165:28080 OUT] Failed to HANDSHAKE with peer 212.83.172.165:28080
2017-06-13 18:42:25.172 [P2P2]  DEBUG   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:918    Connecting to 212.83.175.67:18080(white=1, last_seen: never)...
2017-06-13 18:42:25.172 [P2P2]  INFO    net.p2p src/p2p/connection_basic.cpp:164    Spawned connection p2p#21 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:8
```

Comment: Hard to tell, I'd check your DSL router firewall settings, looks like something is being blocked and not allowing you to initiate connections.

Comment: My modem had open firewall. I deactivated, deleted ".bitmonero" folder and started monerod again. Same thing happened.

Comment: Normally firewalls block incoming connections which can still work. If something is blocking outgoing as well, then it could be the source of problems. Looks like something is killing connection attempts with other nodes, might as well be your ISP. Or something entirely different. You could try to connect to one node at a time to see what's happening, using --add-exclusive-node \<IP>. Here's some IPs you could use https://moneroworld.com/#nodes

Comment: I've found a node that I can connect via mobile internet, but can't connect via dsl. And found another that works on both. So can we exactly say the problem is not about dsl router, it is about ISP ? Maybe my ISP denies connections from some ports...

Comment: The port is always the same (18080), so it could actually be blocking some ranges of IP addresses. Glad you figured it out, gonna compile this into an answer.

Comment: Port was not same, starting with 65.

Comment: I was wrong, might as well be the port that is blocked. The port 18080 is the default port nodes listen to, but a node can be started to listen at any port. Maybe thanks to that special one listening at an unusual point, you were able to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, connections with other nodes are being prevented by something external. It could be:

- firewall software on your computer
- your own firewall, if you have one (usually built into the router)
- your ISP
- other nodes blocking your IP (could be their ISP, or you're on their banlist for whatever reason). This could also be if you share IP with many other people, and one of those somehow got the IP on a blacklist.

If your firewalls allow outbound connections to any port, then it must be one of the latter. This can be tested by trying to manually connect to some known list of nodes one by one and check if any work. You can do this by starting the daemon with `monerod --add-exclusive-node <IP>`, and a list can be found [here](https://moneroworld.com/#nodes)